# Website Redirect if not login

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is my login form. aka index.php

```
<form class="form-3" action="login.php?log=ok" method="post" >
   <input type="text" name="username" id="login" placeholder="Username">
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"> 
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                     
</form>
```

And here is my login checker. aka login.php

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/Personel.php';
$personel = new Personel();
$personel->setUsername($_POST['username']);
$personel->setPassword($_POST['password']);
$personel->login();

header("Location: index.php");


// REDIRECT
session_start();
if (strcasecmp($personel->getRole(), "LTO") == 0   ) {
    $_SESSION['role'] = "LTO";
    $_SESSION['personel'] = $personel;
    header("Location: LTO");
}else if(strcasecmp($personel->getRole(), "LTFRB") == 0){
     $_SESSION['role'] = "LTFRB";
    $_SESSION['personel'] = $personel;
    header("Location: LTFRB");
}else if(strcasecmp($personel->getRole(), "LGU") == 0){
     $_SESSION['role'] = "LGU";
    $_SESSION['personel'] = $personel;
    header("Location: LGU");
}else if(strcasecmp($personel->getRole(), "ADMIN") == 0){
     $_SESSION['role'] = "ADMIN";
    $_SESSION['personel'] = $personel;
    header("Location: admin");
}
?>
```

now when i try to access any accounts from them i can easily open its `index page` and other pages even i'am not login. How can i prohibit that? and how can i avoid the url rewriting?

eg. the index page of admin

try to open my [link](http://itravel.cloudapp.net/itravelWeb2/index.php) the correct account is admin-admin also try a wrong one..

Big Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling header("Location: index.php") without any condition? That means that you are always redirecting to index.php.

Comment: You've kept a redirect to index.php outside any condition. I don't see how your session code can work! Also, what does `$personel->login()` does? Does it redirect somewhere?

Comment: @Tzar When i try to input correct accounts. i goes to the expected page. While if i try wrong accounts it stays with the index.php that why i thought is is correct

Comment: Is anything stored in your `$_SESSION` variable? Cause it seems that whole block will never be executed if it keeps redirecting to index.php

Comment: try to open my [link](http://itravel.cloudapp.net/itravelWeb2/index.php) the correct account is admin-admin also try a wrong one..

Comment: Check the edit. You need to implement a check mechanism before each of your pages to check if the session variable is correctly set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you need to set the redirect to index.php in proper place, with some condition.

I get your problem, but are you checking the session on each and everypage?

You need to implement a check at the beginning of each page that whether the session is properly set or not. Else redirect back to index.php.

You need to implement this code before each of your pages:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['role'])){
   if($_SESSION['role'] != "ADMIN") { //change the "ADMIN" to your unique role per page
      echo "Access denied";
      exit();
   }
else {
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: i think you mistyped?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling header("Location: index.php") without any condition.
That means that you are always redirecting to index.php.

Any call to login.php will result in automatic redirect to index.php.

I don't know what $personel->login() exactly does but your code should look something like:

```
$authorized = $personel->login();

if (!$authorized) {
   header("Location: index.php");
   exit();
}
```

Also - session_start() should be at the top of the code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `session_start()` can be anywhere in the code, unless and untill there are no `$_SESSION` variables above it!

Comment: try to open my [link](http://itravel.cloudapp.net/itravelWeb2/index.php) the correct account is admin-admin also try a wrong one..

Comment: @Tzar I'm aware of that, it's just good practice to place it at the top to avoid future problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a check at the top of every page, and if user not logged in redirect them to an appropriate page, for example a login page.

Here's one approach to doing this.

When you login, set a $_SESSION variable (something like `user_id`), like this:

```
//If successful login:
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid_from_the_db;
```

Note that when using sessions, you must place `session_start();` at the very TOP of each page.

Then, you can check if the user is logged in before displaying any page data.

Something like:

```
<?php
    protect_page();
```

Where protect page can look like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])===false) {
    echo '<p>Please log in first</p>';
    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5; url=login.php">';
}
```

Consider viewing this (free) tutorial from phpAcademy:

[Registration and Login - Procedural version](https://phpacademy.org/videos/register-login-old)

[Registration and Login - OOP version](https://phpacademy.org/videos/oop-loginregister-system)

---

Notes:

You can use either of these methods to redirect the page:

`header("Location: pagename.php");`

This is the preferred way, however you cannot output any other headers before using this command or it will fail.

`<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5; url=pagename.php">`

As a work-around, you can use this method to redirect the page, and the bonus is that it will wait the specified number of seconds before doing so (5 in this case, or zero if you choose).